# How can I fix the cudnn_cmake_module error when building Autoware with colcon?

Tags: ros, cudnn, colcon

--- stderr: trtexec_vendor
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
By not providing "Findcudnn_cmake_module.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"cudnn_cmake_module", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"cudnn_cmake_module" with any of the following names:

```
cudnn_cmake_moduleConfig.cmake
cudnn_cmake_module-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "cudnn_cmake_module" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "cudnn_cmake_module_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "cudnn_cmake_module" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.

---

I already installed cudnn and used it whole the times.
How can i fix this error?

I was trying to install 'autoware_galactic' and

when i tried 'colcon build' that error was occurred

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to migrate from ROS to ROS2 and still not used to those errors. This error confused me for a couple days but the solution is kind of easy.
It turns out that this is similar to package missing errors in ROS.

You are using galactic, right?
If so, there is a package name `ros-galactic-cudnn-cmake-module` you can install directly thru apt.

```bash
sudo apt install ros-galactic-cudnn-cmake-module
```

You can replace the galactic to your ros2-distro such as humble in the future.

Hope this help. This is my first answer on Stackoverflow :)